# Update values of object in database onchange or onevent Angular2

Tags: data-binding, io, angular

I wonder if it's ok to update database on every changes on model in angular2. I think it would cost too much resources. Instead i should update database with the binded model only on specific events. Is there a 'best way' to do it or it's up to me and it depends on the app?

Comment: This might depend on the kind of application you're building. Do you want your user to cancel an edit? How do you know how to reset the old state when (for example) every keypress was sent to the server. It's easiest to use a safe and cancel button. It might be appropriate to have auto-safe as default behavior when the user navigates away.

Comment: I'm just thinking in general, looking for pros and cons, hoping smarter guys with more experience will give usefull advices.

Comment: Pros and cons depend on the kind of application you want to build ;-)

Answer (score 1):

IMO, in the most cases it is better and efficient to update the database on a specific event. Mostly is clear at which time a record is complete and should be written to the database (for example a submit or a button click). But In some cases you have no specific point and than maybe, its ok to save on every change.